Custom locale facets get ignored by std::locale::category
I have created a custom locale facet by specializing std::ctype for int32_t, to accommodate my std::basic_string<int32_t>.
namespace std
{
    template <>
    class ctype<std::int32_t> : public std::ctype_base
    {
    public:
        static std::locale::id id;
        // other members
    };
}

However, I find that this facet gets ignored completely by std::locale::ctype when reusing facets from another locale:
using my_ctype = std::ctype<int32_t>;
std::locale custom_loc(std::locale::classic(), new my_ctype());
auto my_facet = &std::use_facet<my_ctype>(custom_loc);

std::locale default_loc(std::locale(""), new my_ctype());

std::locale with_original_ctype(default_loc, custom_loc, std::locale::ctype);
bool b = my_facet == &std::use_facet<my_ctype>(with_original_ctype); // false

std::locale everything_replaced(custom_loc, default_loc, std::locale::all);
bool c = my_facet == &std::use_facet<my_ctype>(everything_replaced); // true

At least on MSVC, even though with_original_ctype should reuse all std::locale::ctype facets from custom_loc, it did not use my_facet (instead keeping the one given to default_loc). Worse even, everything_replaced, despite being constructed with std::locale::all taken from default_loc, still retains the original my_facet.
How do I make the facet be correctly interpreted as being in the category std::locale::ctype?

What class templates with a ctype<int32_t> are you using?int32_t is a rather odd char_type.

@TedLyngmo I use std::basic_string<int32_t> and std::basic_regex<int32_t> for a specific scenario. I don't think this causes the issue however.

AFAIK you can't add a new facet to an existing category.
